# fixing the form view to hide the field of authenticated user in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

my **models.py** is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    asker = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questions')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Question,Choice
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm


class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ('question','votes','pub_date','slug')

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('asker','pub_date',)

class PollForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'question':QuestionForm,
        'choice':ChoiceForm,
    }
```

**views.py**

```
class PollPost(CreateView):
    form_class = PollForm
    template_name = "blog/post.html"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        question = form['question'].save(commit=False)
        question.asker = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        question.save()
        choice = form['choice'].save(commit=False)
        choice.question = question
        choice.save()
        return HttpResponse("congrat")
```

blog/post.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="POST">
      <div class="text-left">{% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

i used another view to find the problem and i think django consider it invalid form
views.py

```
def poster(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = PollForm(request.POST)
        print(1)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form['question'].save(commit=False)
            question.asker = request.user
            question.save()
            choice = form['choice'].save(commit=False)
            choice.question = question
            choice.save()
            return HttpResponse("congrat")

        else :
            print("unvalid")
            return render(request, 'blog/post.html', 
                          {'form': form})
    else:
        form = PollForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', args)
```

using this view it prints 1 then prints unvalid instead of 2

now the view is not working as i want it gives the asker field and make user choose from users list and and don't hide it and after submitting the form nothing changes in the database and the page doesn't redirected also.

how should i edit the view to make the maximum amount of choices to be three
and make the authenticated user is asker of the question 
thanks in advance

Comment: No errors from Django?

Comment: @Andreas no errors at all

Comment: Could you show the template?

Comment: @FazilZaid i updated the question with the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how should i edit the view to make the maximum amount of choices to be three and make the authenticated user is asker of the question.

You could use Django [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key.

Then, your forms.py would be,

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ('question','votes')

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('asker','pub_date', 'slug')


QuestionFormset = inlineformset_factory(Question, 
                                        Choice, 
                                        fields=('choice_text',),
                                        extra=3,#put number of choices here.
                                        )
```

Your views.py,

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PollPost(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = "blog/post.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PollPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = QuestionFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            context['formset'] = QuestionFormset()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.instance.asker = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            for choice_obj in formset:
                choice = choice_obj.save(commit=False)
                choice.question = self.object
                choice.save()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
```

There would be a slight change in your template,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <form method="POST">
      <div class="text-left">{% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {{ formset }}
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply 
igot this time an errorin the template
ValidationError at /blog/post/
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
and it highlights {{ formset }}

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: (1, 11, 2, 'final', 0) @Fazil Zaid

Comment: Are you sure that your view is exactly like my answer?? Can you specify the error, is it a template error?? There's naming difference in my answer.

Comment: yes @Fazil Zaid
yes it is template error

here is the error message  **Error during template rendering

In template D:\try\v4\mysite\blog\templates\blog\post.html, error at line 7
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with **

and it highlights {{ formset }} in red

Comment: It's working fine in my machine, I m too using Django 1.11. just try removing the LoginRequiredMixin and render again.

Comment: Edited my answer. You had to only add `{{ formset.management_form }}` to your template. It should work now.

Comment: thank You very much sir now it renders perfectly but it doesn't create any choice object and how to change the number of choices @Fazil Zaid

Comment: Is there any errors, you are getting?? I have added `extra` attribute for choices in my answer. You can see what's happening in the view by editing the `form_valid()` method and printing out the variables and save them by your convenience.

Comment: formset.save(commit=False) return empty list

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the data in the formset?? Also, I have edited my answer, try that too.

Comment: i was able to change it so it can save the choices as objects i ll edit your answer so everyone can see it 
thank you very much for your effort

Comment: i was going to edit your answer the same thing it worked now very well thanks

Comment: now i want to make things alittle bit complicated suppose i want choices to be image upload fields instead of textField how should ido it
i've set up my rootmedia and root url in settings.pybut the images dont upload it just creates the objects without uploading the images

Comment: Did you provide an `upload_to` option to the field in `models`??

Comment: YES i provided it and when i use image field in a model and create a form for it it uploads perfectly but here it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry man, I totally forgot. You've got to add `request.FILES` along with `request.POST` in the form initialisation. I'll edit my answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get why ModelForm doesn't exclude the asker field, but you might want to simplify your view:

```
class PollPost(CreateView):
    form_class = PollForm
    template_name = "blog/post.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.asker = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(PollPost, self).form_valid(form)
```

You also might want to use [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) with the view to ensure that you always have self.request.user.

Comment: still the same result can't fix it